# Rstats mean of adjacent values in data.frame

Tags: r

I need some help to solve the following problem :

I have a `47x42 data.frame` with non null values in the upper-diag part, and I need to create a new data.frame based on this one where the value is defined by :

```
new_tab[i,j] <- 1/2 * previous_tab[i,j] + 1/2 * mean(adjacent_cells_of(i,j))
```

For example a smaller data.frame could be :

```
structure(list(X0 = c(10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L), 
X1 = c(2842L, 2842L, 2842L, 2842L, NA), X2 = c(1743L, 1743L, 
1743L, NA, NA), X3 = c(1144L, 1144L, NA, NA, NA), X4 = c(838L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("X0", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4"
), row.names = 15:19, class = "data.frame")

      X0   X1   X2   X3  X4
15 10000 2842 1743 1144 838
16 10000 2842 1743 1144 838
17 10000 2842 1743   NA  NA
18 10000 2842   NA   NA  NA
19 10000   NA   NA   NA  NA
```

My problem is how can i define "mean of adjacent cells" giving that for `[1,1]` value there are only 3 adjacent cells and for `[2,2]` there are 8 values.

The new value of `[2,2]` should be :

```
1/2* 2842 +1/16*(10000+2842+1743+1743+1743+2842+10000+10000)
```

To put it in other words, it's a kind of smoothing values of my original data.frame by the next values. I don't know if i'm clear enough, but i can elaborate if needed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105175/find-neighbouring-elements-of-a-matrix-in-r  It might be useful

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot. I couldn't find a thread on this subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most straightforward solution for finding the mean of adjacent values is good ol' for loop

```
m <- as.matrix(df)
x <- rbind(NA, cbind(NA, m, NA), NA)
z <- matrix(nrow=nrow(df), ncol=ncol(df))
for (i in 2:(nrow(x)-1)){
  for(j in 2:(ncol(x)-1)){
    y <- x[(i-1):(i+1), (j-1):(j+1)]
    y[2,2] <- NA
    z[i-1, j-1]= 1/2 * x[i, j] + 1/2 * mean(y, na.rm=TRUE)
  }
}
z
       [,1]     [,2]     [,3]   [,4] [,5]
[1,] 7614.0 4053.800 1843.000 1255.5  991
[2,] 7852.6 3978.062 1892.929 1293.1   NA
[3,] 7852.6 4218.857 2012.800     NA   NA
[4,] 8210.5 4879.500       NA     NA  NaN
[5,] 8210.5       NA       NA    NaN  NaN
```

Comment: this solution does not use the formula `new_tab[i,j] <- 1/2 * previous_tab[i,j] + 1/2 * mean(adjacent_cells_of(i,j))`

Comment: Yes, that is right, according to the OP,  `1/2* 2842 +1/16*(10000+2842+1743+1743+1743+2842+10000+10000)
#[1] 3978.062`.  May be it is a minor fix

Comment: Thanks, akrun, @MamounBenghezal for clarification

Comment: @MamounBenghezal Thanks for edit. `mean()-x[i,j]` was still insufficient. So I replaced it by `sum`. Hope it achieves what throwic asks.