# Speed up loops and condition with R

Tags: r, for-loop, parallel-processing, data.table, plyr

I would like to speed up this code in R.

The input is an array 3x3x3 containing integer number and based on the neighbors, if they are zero, replace them for the respective number.

The output is the array "mask_roi" with the new values.

```
###### Start here

list_neig = array(0, dim = c(3,3,3))

mask_roi = array(sample(c(0,1,2),27,replace=T), dim = c(3,3,3))

values_mask = array(1:27, dim = c(3,3,3))

values_mask_melted = melt(values_mask, varnames=c("x","y","z"))

### Tranform the 3D Matrix in a data.table wit 4 columns position and value
image_melted  <- melt(mask_roi, varnames=c("x","y","z"))  # 4 columns: x, y, z, value

image_melted$box = rownames(image_melted)

image_melted_non_zeros<-image_melted[!(image_melted$value==0),]

box_neigbors = vector("list", nrow(image_melted))

for (i in 1:(nrow(image_melted_non_zeros))){
  cat(i,"\n")
  x = image_melted_non_zeros[i,1]
  y = image_melted_non_zeros[i,2]
  z = image_melted_non_zeros[i,3] 

  box_neigbors[[image_melted_non_zeros[i,5]]] <- list(nearestNeighbors(values_mask, elem = c(x,y,z), dist = 1,dim = c(3,3,3)))

}
```

I have the "box_neighbors" vector done, just included it here to show how to get it, we need to make faster from here to the end. The idea is, check all voxel different of zero and check all his neighbors. If his neighbor is zero, he will have the same value, if not zero keep it the original.

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(image_melted_non_zeros))){
  cat(i,"\n")  
  x = image_melted_non_zeros[i,1]
  y = image_melted_non_zeros[i,2]
  z = image_melted_non_zeros[i,3] 

  number_of_nei = length(box_neigbors[[image_melted_non_zeros[i,5]]][[1]] )
  value_vozel = mask_roi[x,y,z]  # it will give this new value 

  for (j in 1:number_of_nei){
    nei_number = box_neigbors[[image_melted_non_zeros[i,5]]][[1]][j]

    xx = image_melted[nei_number,1]
    yy = image_melted[nei_number,2]
    zz = image_melted[nei_number,3]     

    value_nei = mask_roi[xx,yy,zz]

    if(value_nei == 0){      
      mask_roi[xx,yy,zz] = value_vozel
    }  
  }  
}
```

I need do this for 256x256x256 array not 3x3x3.

Thanks a lot!

```
nearestNeighbors <- function(ary, elem, dist, dims){
  usedims <- mapply(function(el, d) {
    seq(max(1, el - dist), min(d, el + dist))
  }, elem, dims, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
  df <- as.matrix(do.call('expand.grid', usedims))
  ndist <- sqrt(apply(df, 1, function(x) sum((x - elem)^2)))
  ret <- df[which(ndist > 0 & ndist <= dist),,drop = FALSE]

  return(ary[ret])

}
```

Comment: Which package are you getting `melt` from?

Comment: @BryanGoggin, `melt` comes from `reshape`.

Comment: could you please help me on this one @r2evans ? You are the guy!

Comment: Some confusing things here: how is `box_neighbors` structured? All you show is an empty list. I'm inferring that it's a nested list of sorts. (Several other non-standard/inefficient steps in here that aren't necessarily slowing you down significantly, but they are making it really hard to follow.)

Comment: @r2evans sorry, I forgot to include the part to calculate box_neighbors, now is ok. Thanks

Comment: Have you profiled any of your code to find the biggest culprit? Though systematic `system.time()` captures will give you something, I'd recommend something like [`Rprof`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rprof.html) ([example usage](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~nolan/stat133/Fall05/lectures/profilingEx.html)) or Hadley's newer profiling tool, [`profvis`](https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/).

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the tip, I used profis and I can see where is getting slow, but this is the problem, I can't find a way to avoid the loops "for" and make this code efficient.

Comment: Please use set.seed to make random numbers reproducible, show corresponding expected output and explain (in natural language, not code) how it is derived.

Comment: @r2evans I am giving +50 reputation to someone that solves this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I put together an implementation that uses K-d Trees. It can process a 256x256x256 array in ~13 seconds running on a MacBookPro with 16GB RAM and 2.3 GHz i.7 processor. You didn't give any specific benchmark, but I think 13s is reasonable enough to post an answer. I've outlined my steps below. Please let me know if I have misunderstood part of the question.

**Setup:**

We have a box of side length n filled with points.
A point in the box is determined by coordinates i,j,k which can
range from 1 to n. In total, the box contains n^3 unique points.
Each point has an associated integer value 0, 1 or 2.

**The Problem:**

With box having n = 256.
For each point P having a 0 value, find its k nearest
NON-ZERO-VALUED neighbor and update P with that neighbor's value.
After the update every point in the box should be non-zero.

**Solution:**

Our box has 16,777,216 (256^3) points so brute force methods are out.
Luckily this is exactly what K-d Trees are useful for
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree.
There are a few R libraries focused on metric data structures.
I am using FNN for this example since I think it has a more robust API
than alternatives https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FNN/index.html.

***The Code:***

The box is represented as a matrix with column names (i, j, k, value).
Each row represents a single point in the box.

```
set.seed(256)
library(FNN)
len = 256
values = c(0, 1, 2)
createBox = function(n, vals) {
    index = 1:len^3
    value = sample(vals, length(index), replace = T)
    box = as.matrix(cbind(index, index, index, value))
    dimnames(box) = list(NULL, c("i", "j", "k", "value"))
    box
}
box= createBox(len, values)
```

The knnx.index function accepts the box matrix and a query matrix (subset of box matrix)
as arguments and returns the nearest neighbor indices for each point in the query.

```
updateZeroValuedPoints = function(box, kval) {
  zeroPointIndx = which(box[ , "value"] == 0)
  nonZeroPoints = box[-1 * zeroPointIndx, ]
  zeroPoints = box[zeroPointIndx, ]
  nnIdx = knnx.index(nonZeroPoints, zeroPoints, k = kval, algorithm = "kd_tree")
  zeroPoints[, "value"] = nonZeroPoints[nnIdx[ , ncol(nnIdx)], "value"]
  zeroPoints
}
```

Once you have the neighbor indices it is a straightforward swap to update the values, no for loops required.

```
system.time(updateZeroValuedPoints(box, 1))
# > system.time(updateZeroValuedPoints(box, 1))
# user  system elapsed
# 13.517   1.162  14.676
```

Hopefully this is useful and somewhere near your performance expectations.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick Gerbes, but I dont want to change all zeros, just the ones that have distance 2 of the others ones different of zero. Almost there ;)

Comment: Hey @DemetriusRPaula, could you clarify what you mean by "distance 2 of the others ones different of zero". Once I understand your goal it should be easy enough to tweak the code.

Comment: we have an image here, the number different of zero are lines and zeros are empty space. I would like to make the lines thicker by changing the values of the two closest neighbors of the non-zeros, not all the zeros. @Patrick gerbes

Comment: @DemetriusRPaula, got it. I think I understand now. If we have a line in empty space (represented by a string of non-zero values) we want to find the closest blank pixels and fill them in, effectively making the line thicker. Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes, as we have I 3D image, we need to get at least 2 neighbors in each direction, like a "sphere of neighbors" and replace zero per the non-zero one. The function on my post create this list of neighbors for each non zero ones. Thanks